# PHP MYSQL order the search result by the number of words show up

Tags: php, mysql, search, ranking

I know how to do a regular php mysql search and display the results. However, because of the nature of what I'm trying to accomplish I need to be able count the world/s show up in the column and order the results from highest to lowest. Let me explain this better:

for example my query is: Anything harmless.

1st result:

> find words: **3**
>  id: 12 
>  NAME: self [**harmless**] 
>  DESCRIPTION:
>   [**Anything**] that happens.[**Anything**]that, in happening, causes itself.

2nd result:

> find words: **5**
>  id: 55 
>  NAME: Data mining area 
>  DESCRIPTION:
>   This the extraction [**harmless**] of knowledge significant [**harmless**] newly-hired faculty [**harmless**]in order to [**Anything**] development [**Anything**].

3nd result:

> find words: 1
>  id: **9** 
>  NAME: Programming php sql 
>  DESCRIPTION:
>   the  [**Anything**] members to perform their tasks .

They would rank/display as follows:(base on the number words find).

find words: **5**

> id: 55 
>  NAME: Data mining area 
>  DESCRIPTION:
>   This the extraction [**harmless**] of knowledge significant [**harmless**] newly-hired faculty [**harmless**]in order to [**Anything**] development [**Anything**].

find words: **3**

> id: 12 
>  NAME: self [**harmless**] 
>  DESCRIPTION:
>   [**Anything**] that happens.[**Anything**]that, in happening, causes itself.

find words: 1

> id: **9** 
>  NAME: Programming php sql 
>  DESCRIPTION:
>   the  [**Anything**] members to perform their tasks .

I hope I have explained this well enough and pls. help, i really dont know what to do. im not good in php. im appriciate if you can give me a code or steps. thnk you very much.

```
this is my query: (simplified version)
$query = mysql_query("SELECT thesis_id,thesis_name,thesis_abstract 
    FROM thesis
    WHERE enabled = 1 AND
    MATCH(thesis_name,thesis_abstract) AGAINST('$find' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    OR thesis_name LIKE '%$find%' OR thesis_abstract LIKE '%$find%'
    ")
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query))
  { 
 echo $data['thesis_id'];
echo $data['thesis_name'];
echo $data['thesis_abstract'];
}
```

Comment: Please show the query that you are using to fetch the results (by editing your question).

Comment: have you tried fulltext indexing in mysql? The queries to do this manually will be very inefficient.

Comment: yes, already using fulltext indexing and LIKE query.

Comment: check out `match` and its options.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to create your **own worldcount function** in orther to fill the values of the column 'found words' and then use **usort()** function to get it ordered by this column

Comment: **worldcount function** using php? <br/>  i have this preg_match_all("/$text/i", $string, $matches); /*this will find the search term*/  $count = count($matches[0]); /*count the match word*/       /*inside the while loop*/  $x=1; 
 while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
 $x<=5;    $numbers[$x] = $count; /*inserting into array*/    $x++;   }      rsort($numbers);/*sort the value*/    foreach( $numbers as $value )
    {  
    echo "count $value"; 
   }      it will sort $count but my problem here is how i can display the result? it only get the value of $count but it not get the thesis_id.